# css image not showing on Internet Explorer

Tags: css

css image not showing on Internet Explorer

Image is showing in Chrome and Firefox but I don't know why it's not showing on Internet Explorer. Maybe a CSS problem? Please help me to fix this issue.

This is the complete html page

```
<style>
body
{
background-image:url('gradient2.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
</style>

    <style>
    .shadow1 {
    margin: 7px;
    background-color: rgb(68,68,68); /* Needed for IEs */

    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
    zoom: 1;
    }
    .shadow1 .content {
    position: relative; /* This protects the inner element from being blurred */
    padding: 100px;
    background-color: #DDD;
    }
        .style1 {linkcolor: #000000; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12; color: #999999; font-family: Tahoma; }

    </style>

    </head>

    <head>
        <style type="text/css">    
            .pg-normal {
                color: black;
                font-weight: normal;
                text-decoration: none;    
                cursor: pointer;    
            }
            .pg-selected {
                color: black;
                font-weight: bold;        
                text-decoration: underline;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="paging.js"></script>
    </head>

 <table id="results">
            <tr>
            </tr>
<tr>
<p class="style1">Latest Actress</p>
<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Sherlyn Chopra" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Sherlyn Chopra/10.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Sherlyn Chopra</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Sherlyn Chopra" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Sherlyn Chopra/1.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Sherlyn Chopra</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Evelyn Sharma" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Evelyn Sharma/2.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Evelyn Sharma</p></td>
      </tr><tr>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Kajal Aggarwal" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Kajal Aggarwal/1.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Kajal Aggarwal</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Kainaat Arora" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Kainaat Arora/1.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Kainaat Arora</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Veena Malik" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Veena Malik/8.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Veena Malik</p></td>
      </tr><tr>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Sonakshi Sinha" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Sonakshi Sinha/4.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Sonakshi Sinha</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Kareena Kapoor" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Kareena Kapoor/27.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Kareena Kapoor</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Jacqueline Fernandez" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Jacqueline Fernandez/2.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Jacqueline Fernandez</p></td>
      </tr><tr>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Deepika Padukone" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Deepika Padukone/1.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Deepika Padukone</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Chitrangda Singh" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Chitrangda Singh/3.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Chitrangda Singh</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Asin" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Asin/1.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Asin</p></td>
      </tr><tr>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Ameesha Patel" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Ameesha Patel/1.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Ameesha Patel</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Amrita Rao" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Amrita Rao/1.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Amrita Rao</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Amrita Rao" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Amrita Rao/amritarao-9.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Amrita Rao</p></td>
      </tr><tr>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Amrita Rao" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Amrita Rao/amritarao-8.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Amrita Rao</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Amrita Rao" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Amrita Rao/amritarao-7.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Amrita Rao</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Amrita Rao" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Amrita Rao/amritarao-6.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Amrita Rao</p></td>

</tr>
</table>

<div id="pageNavPosition"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript"><!--
        var pager = new Pager('results', 2); 
        pager.init(); 
        pager.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition'); 
        pager.showPage(1);
    //--></script>

    </body>
```

Comment: Is is an RGB image? Do you have a link?

Comment: There are/where problems with Internet Explorer not showing images in CMYK. Are you sure the image is in RGB colors?

Comment: yes dear its rgb color image

Comment: Your HTML is malformed for one thing -- link tag is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 closing head tags and no opening body tag.
I'd first start by cleaning up your html first and see if that helps.

ie.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-image:url('gradient2.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
.shadow1 {
    margin: 7px;
    background-color: rgb(68,68,68); /* Needed for IEs */

    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(68,68,68,0.6);

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";
    zoom: 1;
}
.shadow1 .content {
    position: relative; /* This protects the inner element from being blurred */
    padding: 100px;
    background-color: #DDD;
}
.style1 {linkcolor: #000000; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12; color: #999999; font-family: Tahoma; }
.pg-normal {
    color: black;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;  
    cursor: pointer;    
}
.pg-selected {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;      
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="paging.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="results">
<tr></tr>
<tr>
<p class="style1">Latest Actress</p>
<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Sherlyn Chopra" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Sherlyn Chopra/10.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Sherlyn Chopra</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Sherlyn Chopra" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Sherlyn Chopra/1.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Sherlyn Chopra</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Evelyn Sharma" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Evelyn Sharma/2.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Evelyn Sharma</p></td>
      </tr><tr>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Kajal Aggarwal" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Kajal Aggarwal/1.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Kajal Aggarwal</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Kainaat Arora" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Kainaat Arora/1.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Kainaat Arora</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Veena Malik" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Veena Malik/8.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Veena Malik</p></td>
      </tr><tr>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Sonakshi Sinha" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Sonakshi Sinha/4.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Sonakshi Sinha</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Kareena Kapoor" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Kareena Kapoor/27.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Kareena Kapoor</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Jacqueline Fernandez" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Jacqueline Fernandez/2.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Jacqueline Fernandez</p></td>
      </tr><tr>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Deepika Padukone" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Deepika Padukone/1.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Deepika Padukone</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Chitrangda Singh" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Chitrangda Singh/3.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Chitrangda Singh</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Asin" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Asin/1.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Asin</p></td>
      </tr><tr>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Ameesha Patel" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Ameesha Patel/1.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Ameesha Patel</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Amrita Rao" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Amrita Rao/1.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Amrita Rao</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Amrita Rao" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Amrita Rao/amritarao-9.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Amrita Rao</p></td>
      </tr><tr>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Amrita Rao" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Amrita Rao/amritarao-8.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Amrita Rao</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Amrita Rao" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Amrita Rao/amritarao-7.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Amrita Rao</p></td>

<td><a href="actress/wallpaper.php?wallpapers=Amrita Rao" target="_blank" class="style1"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="actress/Amrita Rao/amritarao-6.jpgthumb.jpeg" width=260 height=172 /><p  class="style1">Amrita Rao</p></td>

</tr>
</table>

<div id="pageNavPosition"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
        var pager = new Pager('results', 2); 
        pager.init(); 
        pager.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition'); 
        pager.showPage(1);
//--></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing that you have here that would indicate something that would trigger an issue in Internet Explorer. That says to me that there is something wrong with your code as a whole, which doesn't translate well to here.

There are a couple of things to do to help potentially fix the problem, or at least get you to a point that something changes such that you'll be able to make strides to fix the problem:

1. **Validate your code** A lot of novices make mistakes that are easily fixed by simply making sure that your code is correct. [The W3C provides a nice validator tool](http://validator.w3.org/) to help fix issues.
2. **Ensure nothing precedes the DOCTYPE declaration** Once your code passes the W3C's validation, make sure you have nothing before the DOCTYPE declaration. If you do, it will throw Internet Explorer into what's known as Quirks Mode, which will make it render things in a non-standard, and not really predictable manner.

If it still doesn't work, then you'll need to provide us a link to your site so we can see what's going on with your code as a whole.